# How to sort a list by some properties (only one entry of the list) C++

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I have a list representing many characteristics of a fish (Trout). One of these characteristics is the length of the organism (L). I coded multiple Trouts, so eventually in my list "Trout" there are many fishes characterized by the same types of property. I would like to sort my list by decreasing order of only one property (length), so that the first object of my list is the longest fish and so on. I could not find an helpful post on C++, I hope somebody can help me to solve faster this problem, thanks!

I have tried to zip together the Trout list with a list of only length, to sub-sequentially sort by Length and then select only the Trout entries, but I did not succeed.

```
C++

 class Trout {
         public:
              string species;
              double U_E, V, U_H, U_R; 
              double e_scaled, L;
              double SA, SC; 
              int age, mom_birth, mom_metamorph, mom_maturation;
              double scatter; 
              int ag_step;
              double age_acc, h_acc, Hazard; 
              bool spawn;
              int year_reproduction;
              int day_reproduction;
              int day_birth;
              int year_birth;
            double L_j;
            double L_b ;
            double pA_m_surf, Ub_H, Uj_H, Up_H, g, J_X_Am, E_m_vol, pX_m, L_max;

  Trout(string spc, double aa, double bb, double cc, double dd, double ee, double gg, double hh,
                    int oo,int mb, int mom, int mmat, double ind_variability,  double aging_acceleration,
                    double hazard_rate, double Hazard_f, bool spw, int year_r, int day_r, int day_b, int year_b,
                    double MaxassRate, double matB, double matJ, double matP,
                    double EnRatio, double ingRate, double Edensity, double EingRate, double LengthM,
                    double Lb_sc, double Lj_sc);
              virtual ~Trout(){}
              void printFriendInfo();
      };

      Trout::Trout(string spc, double aa, double bb, double cc, double dd, double ee, double gg, double hh,
                   int oo,int mb, int mom, int mmat, double ind_variability ,  double aging_acceleration,
                   double hazard_rate, double Hazard_f, bool spw, int year_r, int day_r, int day_b, int year_b,
                   double MaxassRate, double matB, double matJ, double matP,
                   double EnRatio, double ingRate, double Edensity, double EingRate, double LengthM,
                   double Lb_sc, double Lj_sc)
      {
        species = spc;
        U_E = aa;  U_H = bb;  U_R = cc;
        e_scaled = dd;

        L = ee;

        SA = gg; SC = hh;
        age = oo;
        mom_birth = mb;  mom_metamorph = mom;  mom_maturation = mmat;
        scatter = ind_variability;
        age_acc = aging_acceleration;
        h_acc = hazard_rate;
        Hazard = Hazard_f;
        spawn = spw;
        year_reproduction = year_r;
        day_reproduction = day_r;
        day_birth = day_b;
        year_birth = year_b;
        pA_m_surf = MaxassRate;
        Ub_H = matB;  Uj_H = matJ;   Up_H = matP;
        g = EnRatio;
        J_X_Am = ingRate;
        E_m_vol = Edensity;
        pX_m = EingRate;
        L_max = LengthM;
        L_b = Lb_sc;
        L_j = Lj_sc;
      };
```

Comment: ot: some consider more than 3 parameters to a function as too much. To some extend it is a matter of style but your function definitely takes too many

Comment: "I have tried to zip together the Trout list with a list of only length, to sub-sequentially sort by Length and then select only the Trout entries, but I did not succeed" ... please show the code. To sort for a custom predicate you can pass the predicate to `std::sort`

Answer (score 3):

Use std::sort with a custom comparator (in my example with a lambda).

```
std::vector<Trout> trouts;
auto cmp = [](const Trout& lhs, const Trout& rhs){ return lhs.L < rhs.L; };
std::sort(trouts.begin(), trouts.end(), cmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy to achieve. I am going to assume a few things (and explain them as I go along).

Say you have a `vector<Trout>` and want to sort it in descending order of each Trout's length. Following code will do the job fine.

```
vector<Trout> trouts(fill_collection()); // returns a vector of trouts from somewhere.

sort(begin(trouts), end(trouts), [](const auto& a, const auto&b)
{
    return a.length < b.length; // assuming there's a public field length available in trouts.
});
```

Or you can define a `operator<()` for your Trout objects which will be automatically picked by `sort()`.

```
bool operator<(const Trout& a, const Trout& b)
{
    return a.length < b.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have a *list*, here's another way working with [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Alternatively to defining `operator <`, one can define a cast operator to a standard type, e. g.:

```
 class Trout
 {
         public:
            operator double () { return -L; }
            …
 }
 …
     // presumed you have a list <Trout> l, you can now sort it by just doing:
     l.sort();
```

I negated the `return` value since you want to sort in *decreasing order*.

Of cource this is only usable if you only ever want to sort on the *one property (length)*.